# python mysql connection via ssh

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to connect to MySQL via ssh in Python. However, it keeps giving me `(2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')` error.

Is this related to permission? If it does, what do I need to do? Any suggestion or advice would be appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

**python.py**

```
with sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
    (SOME_IP, 22),
    ssh_username='user',
    ssh_password='password',
    remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3306),
    local_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3306)
) as tunnel:
    db = MySQLdb.connect(
        host='127.0.0.1',    
        port=3306,
        user="user",         
        passwd="password",  
        db="DBName",  
        charset='utf8'
    )

cur = db.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM DB_TABLE")

drivers = cur.fetchall()

db.close()
```

Comment: Can you double check the indentation in the code snippet you've pasted? It looks like you're leaving the `with sshtunnel` context which would close the connection

Comment: @PeterGibson I do not understand the problem with indentation. Could you please explain more details please? Because what I understand from the code above is that when `with sshtunnel` part and `as tunnel` part is done, `cur = db.cursor()` is executed.

Comment: `cur = db.cursor()` is outside of the context handler so SSHTunnelForwarder's `__exit__` has been called. I think that means that the tunnel has been closed by the time you try to use the cursor and that could be bad.

Comment: Indent all of the db lines and it should work.

Comment: @Peter Gibson @tdelaney Thank you so much! It works! One more question is that do I need to close ssh connection? If I do, how do I do this? I know db has been closed with `db.close()` but i am not familiar with `sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder`